# Hardhat get last block timestamp, block number, block hash, nonce, gas limit, gas used

Tags: hardhat, waffle

How to get last block information in a Hardhat Waffle test?

I checked here
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/#json-rpc-methods-support

And here
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/

it seems eth_blockNumber is what I need, but how can I use it to get the last block timestamp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` (and you are if you have `@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle` installed and imported in your config), then:

```
const latestBlock = await hre.ethers.provider.getBlock("latest")
```

Notice that `ethers.provider` is something added by the `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` plugin, it's not part of ethers itself. It's a provider that is connected to the network that Hardhat is using.

Comment: Franco, thank you so much. I think "hre." is not needed :)

Answer (score 5):

To answer:

> how can I use it to get the last block timestamp?

And adding to the previous answer to get the timestamp just read the property from the returned block information:

```
const timeStamp = (await ethers.provider.getBlock("latest")).timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Hardhat and doing tests, you can get the timestamp of a block where a specific transaction was included

```
 it('should succeed - verify the timestamp when a token was minted', function () {
   const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

   //mint something ~ the contract stores the block.timestamp during the mint

   expect(yourTx = await yourContract.connect(accounts[1]).mintNFT(
                randomParameters,
                moreRandomParameters,
                {value: yourMintPrice})).to.be.ok

   //Print timestamp from the specific block where a TX was included

   const foo = await ethers.provider.getBlock(yourTx.blockHash!)
   console.log(`timestamp of the tx ${foo.timestamp}`)

   //this function returns the token details stored in the contract

   const mintedToken = await yourContract.getTokenDetails(mintedTokenId)
   console.log(`tokenstoredTimestamp ${mintedToken.timestamp}`)


   expect(mintedToken.timestamp).to.be.equal(foo.timestamp)

        });
```

The previous answers are correct, this is just a different approach to get a bit more control if you are running parallel tests and your functions are time sensitive